# How do I look for a file on disk that matches a regex? (e.g. /123-foo serves up /123-bar.html)

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to dynamically look up file names as part of `try_files` or some other directive?

I want to have `123-bar.html` in my directory, and have it served up to any URL that is prefixed with `123`. So `123-foo`, `123-baz` etc should all match it. I know how to make it work hard-coded, but I'm wondering if there's some way to regex match the file names that get served up.

Comment: Not with plain Nginx. You may be able to search directories using LUA or Perl extensions.

Comment: Okay thanks for that. One problem I realized is that multiple URLs would serve a 200 for the same content, which I think search engines don't like.

My approach now is to construct a redirects named location as part of the site build:

     location / {
       try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri =404;
     }
     
     location ~ /(\d+)-.*$ {
       try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @redirects;
     }
     
     location @redirects {
       rewrite /123-.*$ /123-super-chicken permanent;
     }